# dcc32 Hint H2077 Value assigned to 'objParam' never used

Tags: delphi

When building the application (code below) a hint is displayed:

> H2077 Value assigned to objParam never used

How do I resolve this hint? Is it even applicable in my case?

```
function TESPGenerateParamList.RandomizationTimeConfiguration(SRandomizationTimeNode: string; eConfigType: string): Boolean;
var
  objParam: Param;
  sFirstNode : string;
  nStartPos,nEndPos : word;
begin
  try
    try
      objParam := ParamSchedulerRandomizationTime.Create;
      if eConfigType = 'SETPARAM' then
      begin
        ParamSchedulerRandomizationTime(objParam).FrameType := Set_Param;

        //TIMEOUT Node
        sFirstNode := '';
        if SearchNode(rsMinutes,SRandomizationTimeNode,sFirstNode,nStartPos,nEndPos,false) then
        begin
          ParamSchedulerRandomizationTime(objParam).SetParam(0, strtoint(trim(sFirstNode)));
        end;
      end
      else if eConfigType = 'GETPARAM' then
      begin
        ParamSchedulerRandomizationTime(objParam).FrameType := Get_Param;
        ParamSchedulerRandomizationTime(objParam).GetParam(0);
      end;
      slConfigurationList.AddObject(objParam.ClassName, objParam);
      result := true;
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        LogErrorMessage('uTESPGenerateParamList-->RandomizationTimeConfiguration' + E.Message);
        result := false;
        raise;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    objParam := nil;  //(for here it give hint)
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Do you need to free it rather than set its value to nil?

Comment: what code i write to free objparam

Comment: if it is a class use:
objParam.free;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is absolutely correct. You don't refer to the variable after that assignment. The next thing that happens in all cases is that the function terminates.

To resolve the hint, delete the assignment statement entirely. Then you can remove the surrounding `try`-`finally` block, too, since nothing happens in the `finally` section.

**But** that's assuming the assignment statement was the proper way to dispose of the referenced object in the first place. It's probably not, if `Param` is a class type rather than an interface. In that case, keep the `try`-`finally` block, but replace the assignment with `Param.Free`, just like you've surely seen in dozens of other Delphi examples. Then, move the initial `objParam` assignment up two lines so it occurs *before* you enter the first `try` section.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, @Chetan. Please post a new question. Comments are no good for that.